# how to alert view controller remove from window

Tags: ios, swift3, uialertview

I'm new to swift . I want to remove alert view from window. So my question is when alert view show it under the window .If so how can I remove alert view from window proper way .

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Whoops", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

if your need more information let me know please.
Thanks!

Comment: FYI - you do not need to call `dismiss` inside the handler for your OK button.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks . i update my code . how can i remove alert view from `window`

Comment: You also do not need the self before present